# ¿Cómo insertar registro con formato fecha a mysql?

Tags: mysql, python, csv, date

Estoy leyendo un archivo **csv** el cual quiero insertar a `mysql` mediante un script en **Python**.

El archivo **csv** contiene campos con formato **string** y otros con formato **DATE** o **fecha**.

¿De qué manera puedo **castear** el campo para poder insertarlo como fecha tomando en cuenta que en **mysql** se inserta aa/mm/dd?

Cuento con el siguiente código:

```
with open ( 'registro.csv') as file:
entrada = csv.reader(file)
for reg in entrada:
    print (reg)

with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (id, nombre, apaterno, amaterno, fecha_nacimiento) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            val = reg
            cursor.execute(sql,val)
            conexion.commit()
```

Comment: Ese código no es donde está el problema. Debes presentar el código donde recibes los datos del csv y los pasas a la consulta.

Comment: He agragado la parte que mencionas @A.Cedano

Comment: Ok en este bucle `for reg in entrada` puede determinar en qué posición está el dato que quieres formatear y formatearlo a `aaaammdd`

Comment: No, solamente obtengo registro (fila) completo

Comment: ¿O sea en cada `reg` están todos los valores separados por comas a insertar?

Comment: Hola Paul, `reg` es una lista de cadenas, dónde laa fecha es `reg[4]`, basta con formatear la fecha de forma adecuada en la lista antes de pasarla a la consulta, para ser más concretos habría que saber que formato tiene la fecha exactamente en el csv originalmente... Si tu colulmna es de tipo DATE en principio debería aceptar un objeto datetime.datetime directamente.

Comment: Exacto, reg es cada registro a insertar. No los separo por posiciones.

Comment: Paul como comento arriba, para poder ayudar es imprescindible conocer el formato de la fecha en el csv, un csv no tiene campos con formato o tipo, todo son cadenas.Se puede modificar laa cadena para adecuarla aal formato esperado o parsearla a `datatime.date` que debería ser aceptada (no se que conector usas...): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html. Esto es simple, pero hay que saber de que partimos, agregar un par de filas del csv siempre ayuda a crear un [mcve], obviamente modificando campos con información sensible si los hay. Un saludo.

Comment: Estos son algunos de los registros posibles:                                                   
1   juan   ramirez   garcia   December 4, 2018
||    2   jose   fernandez   morales  July 23, 2019

Comment: ¿Las lineas están exactamente así? Lo digo porque si el espacio es el separador `December 4, 2018`  debería estar acotado para evitar que el espacio entre mes y dia y el que hay después de la coma se tomen como separadores....

Comment: Así es, entre el mes y el dia hay un espacio, sigue la coma  y otro espacio entre la coma y el año. December 4, 2018

Comment: Si las fechas vienen así `December 4, 2018` lo más simple será crear  un objeto `DateTime`, con esa parte del csv en específico, lo cual significa que tienes que tratar los datos por separado, no como una cadena sin más, o bien, si depende de ti, cambiarlos en la fuente (csv)  de modo que vengan listos para insertar. De todos modos no conozco Phyton, quizá @FJSevilla puede echarte una  mano con el código en concreto.

Comment: @PaulPadilla el problema es que si la línea viene así tal cual no tienes un csv válido para empezar. Si el separador es el espacio (¿o es el tabulador?). El separador no puede aparecer en un campo sin estar acotado.... ¿Podrías mostrar lo que sale en la terminal con `print(reg)`?

Comment: @FJSevilla así es, es el separador, el campo viene acotado "October 24, 2017"

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de un csv con la estructura:

> 1 juan ramirez garcia "December 4, 2018"
>   2 jose fernandez morales "July 23, 2019"

`csv.reader` retorna una lista por cada fila del csv, con las columnas como items, todas en forma de cadenas (`str`). En tu caso, puedes obtener la fecha simplemente indizando: `fecha = reg[4]` y modificarla antes de pasar la lista a la consulta asignando el nuevo valor aceptado por MySql a ese índice.

La idea general es casi siempre la misma en estos caso, usar `datetime.datetime.strptime` para obtener un objeto `datetime.datetime` a partir de la cadena especificando el formato correcto. Por norma general (siguiendo la API de Python), el conector debería aceptar un objeto `datime.date` para campos `DATE` sin problemas, por lo que puedes hacer algo como:

```
import csv
import datetime

with open ('registro.csv') as file, conexion.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (id, nombre, apaterno, amaterno, fecha_nacimiento) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    entrada = csv.reader(file, delimiter=" ")
    for reg in entrada:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(reg[4], "%B %d, %Y")
        reg[4] = date.date()       
        cursor.execute(sql, reg)
    conexion.commit()
```

En cualquier caso, también podemos pasar el objeto `datetime.datetime` de nuevo a cadena con el formato que queramos usando `datetime.datetime .strftime`. Para "aa/mm/dd" sería `"%y/%m/%d"` ("18/12/04" y "19/07/23" para el ejemplo) y para "aaaa/mm/dd" sería `"%Y/%m/%d"` ("2018/12/04" y "2019/07/23" para el ejemplo)

```
import csv
import datetime

with open ('registro.csv') as file, conexion.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (id, nombre, apaterno, amaterno, fecha_nacimiento) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    entrada = csv.reader(file, delimiter=" ")
    for reg in entrada:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(reg[4], "%B %d, %Y")
        reg[4] = date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        cursor.execute(sql, reg)
    conexion.commit()
```

La clave es usar la cadena de formato adecuada para cada caso, para ver todas las posibilidades, consultar:

- [strftime and strptime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

---

### Edición

Si el csv tiene la siguiente estructura:

> 5 Juan Ramirez Garcia September 10, 2019
>   7 Maria Fernandez Romero January 11, 2019

técnicamente no es un csv. La columna con la fecha debe estar acotada para evitar que los espacios entre el mes y el día y entre el día y el año se tomen como separadores y se generen siete columnas en vez de cinco. Por defecto `csv.reader` toma las comillas dobles como carácter de acotado, pero podría ser cualquier otro siempre que se especifique en el constructor mediante `quotechar`.

Otra posibilidad sería que el csv tuviera efectivamente siete columnas, pero en tal caso, la coma después del día sobra y no debe estar.

Sea como sea, si tu "csv" es como el comentado, podemos corregir el error de forma relativamente simple:

```
import csv
import datetime

with open ('registro.csv') as file, conexion.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (id, nombre, apaterno, amaterno, fecha_nacimiento) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    entrada = csv.reader(file, delimiter=" ")
    for reg in entrada:
        date_str = " ".join(reg[4:])
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%B %d, %Y")
        row = reg[:4] + [date.date()]
        cursor.execute(sql, reg)
    conexion.commit()
```

Comment: He adaptado el ejemplo que me compartiste, sin embargo me aparece un error...    "ValueError: time data '16,' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'". No entiendo a qué se debe...

Comment: Así es, es una fecha "March 16, 2017", Supongo que leé bien el mes pero manda error en el día.

Comment: Acabo e ver la coma detrás del '16,' , creo que la columna fecha no está acotada o no lo está correctamente. Fijate en el ejemplo de csv que coloco, las comillas dobles alredor de la fecha deben estar en el csv (u otro carácter de acotamiento) o no es un archivo csv válido...

Comment: 5 Juan Ramirez Garcia  September 10, 2019
7 Maria Fernandez  Romero  January 11, 2019
    
Justo por eso no entiendo dónde está el error ya que el regristro se encuentra bien acotado.

Comment: `5 Juan Ramirez Garcia September 10, 2019` no es un csv válido, para que lo fuera (acotado) debe ser `5 Juan Ramirez Garcia "September 10, 2019"`, las comillas dobles tienen que estar ahí (eso es el acotado), si no lo están los espacios de la fecha se tomarán como sepadores de columnas cuando no lo son, genrando siete columnas y no 5, quedando la quinta como `10,`. Se pude corregir si tu csv es así, pero ese archivo está mal generado... PAra que lo fuera  o faltan las comillas (u otro caracter que actue como acotador) o sobra la coma después del dia.

Comment: Así es, el dato December 4, 2018 se encuentra tal y como te lo muestro en una sola celda. ¿Entonces ese es el error?

Comment: @PaulPadilla me temo que si, he editado la respuesta, mira al final. Si tu csv es como plantes en tu comentario anterior debería resolver el problema. Obviamente todas las filas deben ser iguales y carecer de acotado todas, Cualquier cosa comenta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105667/discussion-between-paul-padilla-and-fjsevilla).